# Выбрать пользовательские таблицы Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

пытаюсь выбрать пользовательские таблицы во всех схемах базы, но мое регулярное выражение не работает.

Логика такова - выбрать все не служебные таблицы

[image: выражение]

Что происходит на самом деле:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал из документации: like + regexp и  similar to + regexp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В обычном случае пользовательские таблицы - это всё, кроме входящих в схемы `pg_catalog`, `pg_toast*`, `information_schema`. [Именно так](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_10_STABLE/src/backend/catalog/system_views.sql#L570) строится, например, [`view pg_stat_user_tables`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html).

```
 SELECT n.nspname AS schemaname,
    c.relname AS tablename
   FROM pg_class c
     JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
  WHERE c.relkind = 'r'::"char"
  AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
  AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
  AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast';
```

Примерно на такие фильтры полагается `psql` при обработке `\dt` команды.

---

Если рассматривать способы как при этом отстрелить ноги - `pg_catalog` и `pg_toast` в отличии от `information_schema` по-умолчанию [заблокированы](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_10_STABLE/src/backend/catalog/heap.c#L277) для создания новых таблиц. Но и эту проверку при желании возможно обойти. Поэтому в результате таблицы могут быть где угодно. В лучших традициях unix, если вы суперпользователь, то можете стрелять себе в ноги. Но всякие глупости только за свой счёт, о таких таблицах [не будет заботиться](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_10_STABLE/src/bin/pg_dump/pg_dump.c#L1424) даже pg_dump.